# #include <initializer_list> required to use initializer list in range-based for?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

The final C++11 standard includes provisions for range-based for to "just work" for native arrays without having to include `<iterator>` or any other header. This was addressed first, as far as I can tell, in working paper [n2900](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2900.html) as a result of comments UK 78 and 79.

This proposal also included a provision to implicitly `#include <initializer_list>` in every translation unit, so that e.g. the program

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for (auto i : { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 })
        std::cout << i << "\n";
}
```

would be standard-conforming even without including `<initializer_list>`.

However, when concepts were removed from C++11, range-based for was revised as seen in [n2930](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2930.html). While the provision for arrays to "just work" remains, there is no mention that the same is true for initializer lists; indeed the specification that various standard library container headers will `#include <initializer_list>` and the final text of 8.5.4.2 implies the opposite to me.

As far as I can tell, this is pretty close to the final wording on the topic. So, is the program above well-formed with regard to the final standard, or do I need to `#include <initializer_list>` even to use it in a range-based for? Put another way, does the use of an initializer list in a  range-based for constitute a "use of `std::initializer_list`---even an implicit use in which the type is not named" per 8.5.4.2 of the FDIS?

Comment: Pretty sure that's a "yes". What else would your loop be iterating over if not an initializer list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd say yes. According to §6.5.4[stmt.ranged]/1, the statement

```
for (auto i : { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 })
    ...
```

is just equivalent to

```
auto&& __range = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
...
```

and that means an `initializer_list<int>` is used, and the `<initializer_list>` header needs to be included.

Comment: That was my suspicion, but it seems somehow unintuitive. Kind of reminds me how for C++03 every textbook would use `std::endl` but only include `<iostream>` and not `iomanip`.

Comment: @DerrickTurk `std::endl` is defined in `<ostream>`, not `<iomanip>`.

Answer (score 3):

GCC 7.1 produces the following error if `<initializer_list>` is not included:

```
error: deducing from brace-enclosed initializer list requires #include <initializer_list>
     for (auto i : { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 })
                                   ^
```

To see this error one should omit `<iostream>`, because including `<iostream>` will also include `<initializer_list>`.

Comment: Yup, transitive includes will give you a false sense of security that way :-)