# Why do I need to #include <typeinfo> when using the typeid operator?

Tags: c++, rtti, typeid

The [`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) represents a C++ RTTI operator being also a C++ keyword. It returns a [`std::type_info`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info) object that holds (dynamic) type specific information.

From what I understood from various sources, one MUST include `<typeinfo>` when using `typeid`, otherwise the program is ill-formed. In fact, my gcc5.2 compiler doesn't even compile the program if I don't include the before-mentioned header. I don't understand why is a header inclusion mandated for the usage of a C++ *keyword*. I understand mandating a header for whenever we use some object declared/defined in that header, but `typeid` is not of a class type. So what is the reason behind this enforcement of including the header `<typeinfo>`?

Comment: For something similar, `<initializer_list>` also needs to be included in cases you may or may not expect.

Comment: @chris I think only when you explicitly use `std::initializer_list`, which makes a bit more sense, since `std::initializer_list` is a class of its own, not a keyword, although implicitly used by the core language.

Comment: Yes, though there are some trickier cases such as `auto list = {1, 2, 3};` and `for (auto x : {1, 2, 3}) {}`.

Comment: @chris Yes, but do you have to include the header in the case you just mentioned? From what I know, the type is deduced as `initializer_list` without the need to include the header. Which is more weird in a sense, since `list` is now of an object type `std::initializer_list`. Ohh yes, you need to include it... Strange and ugly design imo.

Comment: Yep, *if the header <initializer_list> is not included prior to a use of std::initializer_list — even an
implicit use in which the type is not named (7.1.6.4) — the program is ill-formed.* ([dcl.init.list]/2) The link leads to `auto`. As for the second, there's [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913701/include-initializer-list-required-to-use-initializer-list-in-range-based-for).

Comment: I think there's a similar rule for `std::nullptr_t`

Comment: @BenVoigt, It's interesting for sure. The standard provides an explicit definition for it as something really close to "`std::nullptr_t` shall be defined as: `typedef decltype(nullptr) nullptr_t;`"

Comment: @chris And then: *"nullptr is a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t.*

Comment: The reason is "because so". C++ does not make an effort to properly separate the core language from its standard library.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The next paragraph:

> The typeid expression is lvalue expression which refers to an object
>   with static storage duration, of the polymorphic type const
>   std::type_info or of some type derived from it.

Because it is an lvalue expression, which uses [reference initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization) to declare an initializer of `std::type_info`. `<typeinfo>` contains the definition for [that object](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info).

Comment: Probably this is the reason, although I find the design of the language... let's say strange, since it allows a keyword to depend on headers...

Answer (score 6):

`typeid` is not the only one that needs header

`new` also requires header `<new>` in some cases

> Note: the implicit declarations do not introduce the names std, std::bad_alloc, and std::size_t, or any other names that the library uses to declare these names. Thus, a new-expression, delete-expression or function call that refers to one of these functions without including the header is well-formed. However, referring to std, std::bad_alloc, and std::size_t is ill-formed unless the name has been declared by including the appropriate header. —end note

[See abhay's answer on new keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2788548/5475140)

Another operator `sizeof` which returns std::size_t ( It does not actually need to include header, but my point here is that it uses an alias which is also defined in a header)

C++ §5.3.3

> The result of sizeof and sizeof... is a constant of type std::size_t. [Note: std::size_t is defined in the standard header `<cstddef>`(18.2).— end note]

`typeid` use classes which are declared in `<typeinfo>` header

Header `<typeinfo>` synopsis

```
namespace std {
class type_info;
class bad_cast;
class bad_typeid;
}
```

[See section 18.7 on iso cpp paper](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3797.pdf)

IMO, Its C++ Standard Design Techniques, to keep the compiler neat, clean and lightweight

Comment: size_t is a type alias, so you don't need to include the header to use the result of sizeof though

Comment: @AbdulRehman saying "typeid is not the only one that needs header" and then introducing "sizeof" seems like you are saying that sizeof also needs header.

Comment: `new T` doesn't require `<new>`, only certain uses of `new` do. as explained by your quote.