# Why are these C++ headers specified to include <initializer_list>?

Tags: c++, initializer-list

As can be seen from https://stackoverflow.com/a/26614984/481267 the following headers are guaranteed by the standard to `#include <initializer_list>`:

- Everything in [containers]
- `<utility>`
- `<string>`
- `<algorithm>`
- `<random>`
- `<valarray>`
- `<regex>`

Most of these headers declare at least one function that takes a `std::initializer_list<E>` argument, so it makes sense. However,

- `<array>`, `<stack>`, and `<queue>` have no such functions, although perhaps it makes sense to treat all containers uniformly here.
- `<utility>` has no such functions.
- `<iterator>` does have functions with an `initializer_list` argument (`rbegin`, `rend`) but it's not specified to include `<initializer_list>`.

What is the rationale behind these exceptions?

Comment: I think even using uniform initialization requires the inclusion of `<initializer_list>`. See the comments of this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33704978/3093378).

Comment: The inclusion in `<utility>` dates all the way back to N2672. The rest are done by N2930. Free `rbegin`/`rend` are late additions.

Comment: @vsoftco Only if you make use of the type explicitly or implicitly.

Comment: @T.C. That's true, e.g. for something like `auto x = {1,2,3};`, but probably code like this doesn't appear in the standard library.

Comment: @T.C. How did you find those references?

Comment: @brian I believe TC searches git

Comment: @Yakk Most of this predates git, actually. Just did a binary search of old working drafts.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there is no explicit rationale, just that some proposals for additions to the standard were made and those proposals were accepted.

At the very end of the document [N2672 Initializer List proposed wording](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2672.htm) it just says:

> In 20.2 Utility components [utility] paragraph 1:
>
> This subclause contains some basic function and class templates that are used throughout the rest of the library.
>
> Header `<utility>` synopsis
>
> ```
>      #include<initializer_list>
>       namespace std {
> ```

So, the authors of the paper saw `initializer_list` as a utility, and so it ought to be included with the `<utility>` header. And therefore it is.

The paper didn't propose any changes to the `<iterator>` header, so none were made.