# Compiler error when comparing two typeid expressions for equality

Tags: typeid

On this code which comes from a training video:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct MyStruct {
   T data;
};

int main(void)
{
   MyStruct<int> s;
   s.data = 2;
   assert(typeid(s.data) == typeid(int));
}
```

I get this compiler error:

```
class_templates.cpp:12:26: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const std::type_info' and 'const std::type_info')
   assert(typeid(s.data) == typeid(int));
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~
```

compiled with:

```
clang++ -std=c++14 class_templates.cpp
```

Edit: Had I compiled with g++ I would have gotten a better error:

```
class_templates.cpp:14:20: error: must #include <typeinfo> before using typeid
    assert(typeid(s.data) == typeid(int));
```

Comment: You must use `#include <typeinfo>` in order to use `typeid()`

Comment: @Remy Answers go down there -vvvvvvv

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks! That fixes it. Can you make your comment an answer?

Comment: [Why do I need to #include <typeinfo> when using the typeid operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704978/why-do-i-need-to-include-typeinfo-when-using-the-typeid-operator?rq=1)

Comment: Really, two close votes and downvote? SO can be insufferable sometimes.

Comment: One of the clang guys said that they indend to have better error messages than gcc and this is a good opportunity for one. On error on typeid() comparison - note that <typeinfo> not included. But in this case, had I used g++ I would have gotten that very error message that clang is lacking: "class_templates.cpp:14:20: error: must #include <typeinfo> before using typeid 
    assert(typeid(s.data) == typeid(int));"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **must** use `#include <typeinfo>` in order to use `typeid()`, otherwise your program is ill-formed.

Also see:

[Why do I need to #include <typeinfo> when using the typeid operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704978/)